# Problems enabling short_open_tags on travis-ci

Tags: php, apache, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up an existing project for testing on travis-ci, but I'm having problems with turning on `short_open_tags`.

The current setup in `.travis.yml`:

```
before_script:
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi
   # enable php-fpm
   - sudo cp ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf.default ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf
   - sudo a2enmod rewrite actions fastcgi alias
   - echo "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
   - ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/sbin/php-fpm
   # configure apache virtual hosts
   - sudo cp -f build/travis-ci-apache /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
   - sudo sed -e "s?%TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR%?$(pwd)?g" --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
   # short_open_tag
   - sed -i 's/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
   - sed -i 's/asp_tags = Off/asp_tags = On/' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
   - sudo service apache2 restart
```

I've tried simply appending `short_open_tags = On` to the `php.ini`, but read somewhere it makes problems if it's on multiple places, tried adding it via

```
  - phpenv config-add travis.php.ini
```

I created a `.htaccess` file, placed it in the root of the project with this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value short_open_tag 1
 </IfModule>
```

I am a beginner and don't really know what else to try.

Comment: How are you validating that `short_open_tags` aren't being set to the values you want?